# Doing a form POST on ASPx via PHP/CURL

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, curl

:) I would appreciate some help using PHP/ CURL on ASPx.

A similar question to mine was left unanswered from a year ago on StackExchange.

I'm trying to do a HTTP POST to an ASPx page.

I'm able to log in and get to the default view for the page in question. The problem occurs when I try to change options on the page.

There are only two options and when I attempt to do a POST request setting those two options, and making sure I forward the other needed ones like __VIEWSTATE etc, I get a page back with 0 data.

The structure of everything else on the resulting page is almost similar to the default page I encountered except for the missing data - even if I set the two options to the same settings as the default page I encountered.

I believe they have a GridView on the page that's not populating. Is there another "security" procedure I'm missing?

I think it has to do with this:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$cb$reportCommands$linkRun" value="Run Report" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$cb$reportCommands$linkRun&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="cb_reportCommands_linkRun" />
```

More specifically the "onclick" event. That's the button you would normally click to make the change. Any thoughts on how I could deal with that? via PHP / CURL? Thanks lots! :)